# Multiple WebClients not working?

Tags: c#, networking, webclient

I am trying to download three files with three separate WebClients. I use this:

```
    void client1_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CLIENT1");
    }

    void client2_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CLIENT2");
    }

    void client3_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CLIENT3");
    }

    private void mwindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string rand = new Random().Next().ToString();
        WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
        client1.OpenReadCompleted += client1_OpenReadCompleted;
        client1.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/file.exe?r=" + rand));

        WebClient client2 = new WebClient();
        client2.OpenReadCompleted += client2_OpenReadCompleted;
        client2.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/file.exe?r=" + rand));

        WebClient client3 = new WebClient();
        client3.OpenReadCompleted += client3_OpenReadCompleted;
        client3.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/file.exe?r=" + rand));
    }
```

When using this, no matter what I do, only two out of the three WebClients will finish. Using this code, I get two message boxes "CLIENT1", and "CLIENT2", but "CLIENT3" never appears. No exceptions are thrown or anything. Nothing happens. If I reverse the order of the WebClients, `client3` and `client2` work but not `client1`. I have tried changing the code to make the WebClients download one at a time instead of asynchronously:

```
        WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
        Stream str1 = client1.OpenRead(new Uri("http://www.example.com/file.exe?r=" + rand));
        MessageBox.Show("CLIENT1");

        WebClient client2 = new WebClient();
        Stream str2 = client2.OpenRead(new Uri("http://www.example.com/file.exe?r=" + rand));
        MessageBox.Show("CLIENT2");

        WebClient client3 = new WebClient();
        Stream str3 = client3.OpenRead(new Uri("http://www.example.com/file.exe?r=" + rand));
        MessageBox.Show("CLIENT3");
```

However, the program freezes on the `Stream str3 = client3.OpenRead(new Uri("http://www.example.com/file.exe?r=" + rand));` line. Having `client1` download all the files synchronously instead of creating multiple WebClients also freezes on the third file.

Comment: have you tried placing them in different threads?

Comment: just tried it and still no luck.

Comment: your client 2 says only client (last line of client2)

Comment: it works for me if i fix that

Comment: my fault for accidentally messed that up when posting it. isn't causing the problem

Comment: hmm cant seme to recreate the problem. im running it in console though

Comment: Must be specific to your computer / OS / .NET version.

Comment: Win8, VS12 Ultimate, .NET 4,5 so not so much strange there hmm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're experiencing is a combination of two issues. The first one being that the number of concurrent `WebRequest` connections is limited to 2 by default. You can change that by creating a class derived from `WebClient` and overriding the `GetWebRequest` method like so:

```
public class ExtendedWebClient : WebClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the maximum number of concurrent connections (default is 2).
    /// </summary>
    public int ConnectionLimit { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of ExtendedWebClient.
    /// </summary>
    public ExtendedWebClient()
    {
        this.ConnectionLimit = 2;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the request for this client and sets connection defaults.
    /// </summary>
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request != null)
        {
            request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = this.ConnectionLimit;
        }

        return request;
    }
}
```

The second problem I see is that you're not closing/disposing of the `Stream` returned when you call `OpenRead`, so it would appear that the two requests do not complete until such time when the Garbage Collector decides to kick in and close those streams for you.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Wasn't disposing those streams because I wanted to try to reduce the code to the basics.