# C# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse blocks when called from a different Thread

Tags: c#, concurrency, httpwebrequest, deadlock

i just stuck with a problem when i tried to call several web requests in a Task. Here is my code

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var locker = new object();
        var bag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
        var list = new List<Task>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    using (var client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("get");
                        var s = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.de");
                        bag.Add(s);
                        Console.WriteLine("got");
                    }
                }
            });
            list.Add(task);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(list.ToArray());
    }
```

It seems that the very first request blocks and never returns. 
Since the lock is introduced, only one request is send at a time.
So no parellel requests are send.

Does anybody has an idea how to avoid that?
The Thread blocks here:[CallStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKi6P.png)

Comment: google may block your requests. Just open developer window in your browser and see which headers are sent to google. Even you send same headers, you may still get blocked for such frequent requests

Comment: nope, i've tried it with several urls. Even the very first one is already blocked.

Comment: The parallel version does not work either. This is what i dont understand. So it would make sense that if there are too many threads that at some point it breaks. But what i dont get is, that it behaves the same event if only one thread at a time is doing the request.

Comment: Don't know why it deadlocks, but you definitve should not create 5.000 WebClients.

Comment: And in search for a reason for above statement, I probably found the correct dupicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129631/multiple-webclients-not-working

Comment: It is the same behavoir with 100. The amount does  kind of play a role. So with 5, 10 it works a while. But if I create more, even if one thread at a time does the request, it blocks. Its wichcraft :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What happens if you set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;` beforehand?

Comment: Same behavior as before. But it should not interfere with the system, since due to the lock only one thread is sending the request. Is it possible that the werequest needs the maintreahd somehow?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt  I disagree that this is a dublicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129631/multiple-webclients-not-working since only one request is called at a time. Could you please remove the dublicate mark

Comment: Create only one client, and reuse it 5000 times. WebClient also has async methods. If the duplicate does not answer your question, [edit] it and explain why it is not a duplicate.